# .Error CS1061 'Task<IEnumerable>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where'

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, generics, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

My generic repository is as follows ( I have similar in synchronious and it works)

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsyn(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

when I call this:

```
var custDB = await unitOfWork.CustomerRepository
                             .GetAsyn()
                             .Where(c => c.UserId == userID && c.IsDeleted != true)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following error...Can someone help me fix this

> ...Error  CS1061  'Task<IEnumerable>' does not contain a
> definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where'
> accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IEnumerable>' could
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   ..

Answer (score 1):

Because `GetAsyn()` return Task. You need await result of task.

```
var result = await unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAsyn()
var custDB = result.Where(c => c.UserId == userID && c.IsDeleted != true)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Alas! I can only give you one vote. You lifesaver you...

Answer (score 1):

You *could* make this work by calling

```
var customers = await unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAsyn();
var customer = customers.Where(c => c.UserId == userID && c.IsDeleted != true).FirstOrDefault();
```

But that would perform the filtering on the client.  And your "generic repository" doesn't really do anything useful, so you *should* just delete that code and run:

```
var customer = await db.Customers.Where(c => c.UserId == userID && c.IsDeleted != true).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetAsyn` returns a task, you should await it first.

But anyway why would you do the filtering on the client? Your `GetAsyn` method has a `filter` parameter, so you should write it like this:

```cs
var custDbList = await unitOfWork.CustomerRepository
                                 .GetAsyn(c => c.UserId == userID && c.IsDeleted != true)
var custDB = custDbList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if this is still valid or needed ,but here is my input

you just need the ToListAsync() method, which is in the System.Linq.Async  [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) .

some code to help

using part :

```
using System;
sing System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

code :

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getgaAreasList(string silter)
{
    return Json(await new gaAreasVM()
                          .GetAll()
                          .Where(x=>x.name == filter)  
                          .ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: And how does that make room for `Where`?

Comment: i have just changed the code to include where clause

Comment: Doesn't improve anything. The issue is clearly in the forgotten `await` which has [sufficiently been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361017/861716). Also, nobody knows what your code is doing. It's one black box.